# Sharepoint 2016 copy folder with REST api

Tags: rest, 2016, sharepoint-rest-api

I m trying to copy folder with REST api like this

```
/_api/SP.MoveCopyUtil.CopyFolder
```

POST data is

```
{
    "srcUrl": "https://test.sharepoint.com/_api/Shared Documents/CONS0006/PermWPS",
    "destUrl": "https://test.sharepoint.com/_api/Shared Documents/CONS0006/6"
}
```

In response it is showing

```
CopyFolder=(null)
```

And no folder copied

Any idea?

Comment: Your URL seems invalid. Try removing `/_api` from your URLs

Comment: also is your site collection at root level without managed path ?

Comment: @AtishDipongkor thanks a lot for pointing the exact issue, working fine now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_api` should not be include in `srcUrl` or `destUrl`.

```
{
    "srcUrl": "https://test.sharepoint.com/Shared Documents/CONS0006/PermWPS",
    "destUrl": "https://test.sharepoint.com/Shared Documents/CONS0006/6"
}
```

Comment: hi, is it possible to achieve the same with SP2013 rest API or CSOM? please advise for my question [link]https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/213825/sharepoint-2013-rest-api-copy-folder-content-to-another-folder