# Sharepoint 2013 Rest API Copy folder content to another folder

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api, sharepoint-library

I have a Folder whose folder structure must be cloned to another folder in another document library.

Is it possible to do something like using file/folder REST API

```
/_api/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl('{0}')/folder/copyto(destinationpath)
```

or List  REST API

```
/_api/web/lists(guid'{0}')/items({1})/copyto(destiation list/item)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible using this endpoint: **site**/_api/SP.MoveCopyUtil.CopyFolderByPath() and the right parameters as you can see below:

```
var postData = {
   "srcPath":{
      "__metadata":{
         "type":"SP.ResourcePath"
      },
      "DecodedUrl":"https://example.com/sites/<siteName>/folder/<FolderToCopy>"
   },
   "destPath":{
      "__metadata":{
         "type":"SP.ResourcePath"
      },
      "DecodedUrl":"https://example.com/sites/<siteName>/folder/<NameOfNewFolder>"
   },
   "options":{
      "__metadata":{
         "type":"SP.MoveCopyOptions"
      },
      "ResetAuthorAndCreatedOnCopy":true,
      "ShouldBypassSharedLocks":true
   }
};
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "https://example.com/sites/<siteName>/_api/SP.MoveCopyUtil.CopyFolderByPath()",
        data: JSON.stringify(postData),
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest":  $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
        },
        contentType: "application/json; odata=verbose",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
});
```

I hope this will help someone in the future.

Comment: Any option to skip the existing folder if any in the hierarchy?

Answer (score 0):

I haven`t tested the complete code but seems should work for your scenario.

```
<<web url>>/_api/web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('/subsite/Shared%20Documents/sample.txt')/copyTo('/subsite/Shared%20Documents/sample1.txt')
```

The above one is POST end point.

I don`t see any CopyTo end point for folder.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/dff2a79e-c041-4f7a-9890-d0955705a1ed/problem-copying-file-using-rest-api-method-copyto?forum=sharepointdevelopment

MSDN reference for Folder and File end points

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn450841.aspx#bk_Folder